# Euler class of a tensor product bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I want to prove the result:
$$c_1(L\otimes L')=c_1(L)+c_1(L')$$
where $L,L'$ are complex line bundles and $c_1(L):=e(L_{\mathbb R})$. My definition of Euler class is given by the pullback by zero section of Thom class: $$e(E):=s_0^*\Phi(E)$$
In Bott&Tu, this result is proved by writting down an explict formula of Euler class of a rank 2 bundle. I am wondering whether I can prove this by the properties of Thom class.

Comment: Do you know the classification of line bundles and what the thom class of the universal one is?